# software that optimizes caching

Tags: windows-xp, cache

Can you recommend of a free software that can optimize the file cache in windows xp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with the file cache in Windows XP? Any proof that it's not working the best it can?

[**O&O CleverCache**](http://www.oo-software.com/home/en/products/ooclevercache/) pretends to optimize the file cache but I'm not very sure it's improving that much the performance of the computer.

It's not free: 29.90€ (no idea about the price in $).

Comment: I just need to optimize the system. Because xp isn't like ubuntu.
Ubuntu doesnt seem to need any optimizations because its really fast